# Mean Distance From Nearest Neighbor

Tags: probability, probability-theory, optimization, random-variables, random

Let $x_i^{(n)}$ (with $i=1,\ldots,d$ and $n=1,\ldots,N$) be $d\times N$ i.i.d variables, normally distributed with zero mean and unit variance. What is the mean euclidean distance between the vector $(x_1^{(1)},x_2^{(1)}, \ldots, x_d^{(1)})$ and its nearest neighbor among the $N-1$ vectors $(x_1^{(k)},x_2^{(k)}, \ldots, x_d^{(k)})$ for $k=2, \ldots, N$?

Edit: I'm particularly interested in knowing if the nearest-neighbor distance grows linearly with $d$.

Comment: What do you know about this problem?  Are there any values of $d$ and $N$ for which you can solve it?

Comment: I am not sure how to do but I guess the following fits your description: The Euclidean distance between two zero mean multivariate normal follow a scaled chi distribution. Conditional on $X^{(1)} = x^{(1)}$, the Euclidean distance between $X^{(1)}$ and other follows a scaled non-central chi distribution, and you are going to find the distribution of the minimum of them, and then take average with respect to $X^{(1)}$ to obtain the required mean.

Comment: How do you define the distance between $(x_1^{(1)},\ldots,x_d^{(1)})$ and  $(x_1^{(k)},\ldots,x_d^{(k)})$?

Comment: I define the squared distance as $\sum_i (x_i^{(1)} - x_i^{(k)})^2 $, but I would be interested in the answer for other definitions of distance as well.

Comment: If you're only interested in the growth rate, life is significantly easier. Standard concentration bounds show that for $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I_d), $ there exists a $c >0$ independent of $d$ such that  $P( |\|X\| - \sqrt{d}| > t\sqrt{d}) \le 2\exp{(- cd t^2)}.$ So, with $N$ such vectors, with high probability, they all lie within a ball of radius $ \sqrt{d} + O(\sqrt{\log N}),$ and so the minimum distance is $O(\sqrt{d} + \sqrt{\log N})$ (you'll have to make this precise, but the light tail of the bound essentially finishes the job).

Comment: A lower bound of $\Omega(\sqrt{d} N^{-1/d})$ is also easy - again use the concentration to a sphere, and use bounds on the area of a spherical cap to control the largest inner product. See [Chapter 3 here](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~romanv/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf) for a development of the concentration inequality used.